# filtering using the adjacency list model

Tags: postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table of categories using the adjancency list model:

```
category_id, category_name, category_parent_id
1            Armor          NULL
2            Weapon         NULL
3            Chest          1
4            Feet           1
5            Hand           1
6            Light          3
7            Heavy          3
```

and i have a table of items that use this categories

```
item_id, item_name,   category_id
1        Light chest  6
2        Heavy chest  7
```

And i want to filter/get all the items that belong to a specific category (e.g filtering by category_id 1 should return the above table since they are both armor subtypes).

If it's a direct descendant or it has the id directly over category_id is simple but when more than 2 levels are involved it turns confusing for me because it's like you have to recursively check for the parent's category parent until you reach null or you find the matching category.

So the question is: how could i go about making a query to filter items based on a category_id?

Comment: sorry, typo while manually copying the table, it's edited now, it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE)

```
with recursive t as (
    select * from model where category_id=1 
    union all 
    select model.* from model,t where model.parent_category_id=t.category_id
)
select other_table.* from other_table join t using (category_id);
```

Comment: Why are you using a proper JOIN operator in the outer query, but not inside the recursive query?

Comment: Because I wanted to use USING in one spot, but it can't be used in the other one.